# Azure SQL database query performance degradation (cause of Query Store?)

Tags: sql, database, azure, sql-query-store

I have a Azure SQL database (compatibility level = 150).
I'm running into a performance problem executing a database query.

So after I've rebuilt all my indexes, the query runs fast.
When testing, with different parameters, all of a sudden it slows down.
The same query with the same parameters is fast in the beginning, and slow after I do around 50 tests.

Now when I purge the Query store data via the UI or via sql:

```
(ALTER DATABASE [mydb] SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR;)
```

the performance is back.

I've tried all settings on the Query Store, the problem remains, only deleting the data collected gives me back the initial performance.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: For more in-depth Azure SQL questions, you might also try posting to dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

How quickly are you running your tests?
Are you monitoring the database when running tests to see if it is getting throttled?

The Query Store could be producing some overhead. Have you tried running the same tests with the Query Store disabled?

Comment: I've done on the fly tests and tests with some hours in between. Ones the performance is gone, the problem persists until you clear the query store data.

I cannot disable the query store on Azure SQL database. I've changed it to read-only, same problem.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273490/azure-sql-database-query-performance-degradation-cause-of-query-store